# Connection string for multiple computers

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I want to make a connection string using npgsql to connect to my postgres database from many different machines.

I use the following string to connect on my development machine:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5433;Database=DB;User Id=<userID>;Password=<password>");
```

I use port 5433 that's not an error. It works fine and I can access my database and do what I want with my application. The problem is when I'm finished and move the program to different computers, the server will no longer be on "localhost" but on a variety of addresses. What can be done to have a variable connection string?

I do have the postgresql ODBC driver installed and have created a DSN, can I use that in the connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ODBC DSNs with Npgsql, but you can simply put the actual hostname (or IP) of your server instead of `localhost`, that should allow you to connect from any host (as long as the networking and PG permissions allow it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now I have another issue, I'm going to use replication to have the postgres database replicated to another location, so computers from both locations will need to access their respective databases. Only solution is to have the computers that have the databases use the same IP right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... If you have two replicas of your database on each server, then each server has its own hostname (and IP), which means its own connection string.

Comment: For example, with a DSN I could set in odbc options the IP/Hostname for the "DATABASE" and use the same DSN name on multiple computers, at different locations, to connect to the appropriate server. 
With the connection string I'd have to add that IP/hostname change functionality to the program, or make sure my database servers use the same IP on the different locations.
It's not a big deal I was just curious if it could be done in an "automated" way (meaning, without changing the program itself), like when using DSNs

Comment: That sounds like what [pg_service.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) provides; unfortunately, that's not yet supported by the Npgsql driver. I've opened https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4950 to track this.